# How do I bind a generic window to an arbitrary view model at runtime, using DataTemplates?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a large number of ViewModel classes.  For each of these classes, there is a corresponding .xaml file which is a 'UserControl'.  In my App.xaml, I have them registered as DataTemplates, like so:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:MainMenuViewModel}">
     <view:MainMenuView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

With the idea being that WPF will be able automatically swap in the necessary user controls at runtime.  For example, this works:

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="SuperApp" />
        <ItemsControl>
            <ViewModels:MainMenuViewModel/>
        </ItemsControl>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In that the entry "MainMenuViewModel" is automatically replaced by the MainMenuView, bound to the MainMenuViewModel.  Great.  My current goal is now this:  I want to have a button, on, say, a view embedded in the MainMenuView, which opens a popup window, which will have a new ViewModel inside.  The idea is to set it up so that I have a single 'generic' popup form, in which I embed an arbitrary ViewModel, and let WPF handle actually rendering it with DataTemplates, similar to the above.  So I have a command bound to a button, like so:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=LaunchInStandaloneForm}" Content="Rip Out"/>
```

Which successfully creates a new window, sets the dataContext equal to the appropriate ViewModel, and shows the window.

The question is:  How do I set up the XAML of this popup window so that it will render the appropriate DataTemplate for the ViewModel which is the DataContext?  I've tried:

```
 <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">

    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

, but it comes up blank.  Any pointers?

Comment: As an aside, I had assumed that commands on the ViewModel would not do anything with the UI, for example `LaunchInStandaloneForm`.  Could anyone comment on this?

Comment: In this case, the command on the ViewModel is raising an event which is being listened to by a Controller, whose role is to administer windows.  So the ViewModel raises an event like RequestPopupWindow(), and passes the 'requested view' as one of the EventArgs...  The Controller then creates a window, sets the context, and calls showDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `ItemsSource` to the `DataContext`, use `ItemsSource={Binding}`.  That assumes that the `DataContext` is an enumerable collection of your View Model objects.

Updating with correct answer:

Use a `ContentControl` :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: In this case, the DataContext is a view model, not a collection of view models.  I can obviously change it to be one without much difficulty, but it seems more elegant to have a single one there, rather than a collection of one.

Comment: In that case, what is the name of the property that has the collection you're trying to bind to, relative to the DataContext?  Use that as the path, e.g. `ItemsSource={Binding Path=CollectionPropertyOnViewModel}`?

Comment: I don't actually have a collection.  I have a single ViewModel in the DataContext, and I want to render a single DataTemplate for that ViewModel, as the only element on the window.

Comment: I believe I missed your whole point.  You just want it to use the `DataTemplate` you specified :)  Perhaps it's possible to create an `ItemsPresenter` - I know it's usually within a Template though - does that work? I will investigate more now..

Comment: Aha!  Try `ContentControl` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx

Comment: <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>

Worked perfectly!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer here shows how to change templates at runtime. You should be able to dig out the answer from that. Any questions just shout.

[How to modify silverlight combobox data display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335834/how-to-modify-silverlight-combobox-data-display/3343652#3343652)

Hope that helps